# Loading images from cache but return a blank screen

Tags: android, image, caching, bitmap

i try the example i gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045227/android-stop-image-scaling-down/3070654#3070654). The example shows how to display a image that is larger then the screen and the screen acting like a window, allowing user to look at the images via scrolling. However, what i want to achieved is similar just that, instead of one single image, i tried to combining 18 smaller images (171X205) into one single image. I am able to did that but to save loading time on downloading of images from the server, i cached the images. Heres the problem, i cant seems to display the images out on screen even though the images are indeed cached. Thus, i tried something else by fetching image from the drawable folder but still the same issue arise. Does anyone have any idea how to go about solving this problem?

A snippets of code to load images from cache:

```
for(int i =0; i<18; i++)
    File cacheMap = new File(context.getCacheDir(), smallMapImageNames.get(i).toString());
            if(cacheMap.exists()){
                //retrieved from cached
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cacheMap);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)
                        puzzle.add(bitmap);
                     }catch(...){}
             }else{
                 Drawable smallMap = LoadImageFromWebOperations(mapPiecesURL.get(i).toString());
                if(i==0){
                    height1 = smallMap.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    width1 = smallMap.getIntrinsicWidth();
                }
                if (smallMap instanceof BitmapDrawable) { 
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)smallMap).getBitmap();
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        cacheMap.createNewFile();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheMap);
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                        fos.flush();       
                        fos.close(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }       

                    puzzle.add(bitmap);
                }
             }
}
```

**The function where it retrieved images from the server**

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am drawing onto a canvas and so no ImageView is use to display the images.

Comment: I use cache for some of my projects. Post your code that you use to Cache each image when it is downloaded. And post the code that you retrieve them from the cache.

Comment: Actually is right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7543928/918197)

Comment: Okay quick question. How are you loading the images? Like from 18 seperate URL's? I work with cache often and may have a better easier way.

Comment: Added the snippets of code when loading the images. puzzle is just a ArrayList to hold all the 18 images, either from cache or from the server is image no exist in cache.

Comment: Again are you loading these from 18 differenct images by URL's or what?

Comment: yes. 18 different url but from the same server.

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis) returns null value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3782/discussion-between-user918197-and-coder-for-life22)

Answer (score 0):

For all of my lazy image loading I use [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime).